# 2 Mysql table sum column Group and subruction pls

Tags: php, mysql, sql

have

1.Table is.

```
MgName    MgModel     MgIn 
============================
 CPU    |   i5     |   1
 RAM    |   8GB    |   1 
 BOARD  |   ASUS   |   1
 CPU    |   i5     |   2
 RAM    |   4GB    |   1
 RAM    |   8GB    |   1
 CPU    |   i7     |   1
```

2.Table is.

```
McName    McModel   McOut
============================
 CPU   |   i5     |   1
 RAM   |   8GB    |   3
```

3. I want to Same Group Name and same Model SUM then MgIn - MgOut

=

```
StckName  StckModel  StckPce 
============================
 CPU    |   i5     |   2
 RAM    |   8GB    |  -1 
 BOARD  |   ASUS   |   1
 CPU    |   i7     |   1
 RAM    |   4GB    |   1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simple use `UNION` and  a `GROUP BY` clause instead of joining :

```
SELECT t.StckName ,t.StckModel,SUM(t.Mg) as StckPce 
FROM(SELECT MgName as StckName ,MgModel,MgIn as mg as StckModel
     FROM Table1
     UNION ALL
     SELECT McName ,McModel,mcOut*-1
     FROM Table2) t
 GROUP BY t.StckName ,t.StckModel
```

Comment: That would be my solution too, but it should be `-mcOut`.

Comment: Hah, didn't see I forgot it. @ThorstenKettner Thanks for the catch

Comment: And you are missing `GROUP BY t.StckName, t.StckModel`.

Comment: Don't judge me, its morning:) @ThorstenKettner

Answer (score 1):

Here's the query:

```
SELECT 
t.MgName AS StckName,
t.MgModel AS StckModel,
t.summedValue - IFNULL(Table2.McOut,0) AS StckPce
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
   MgName,
   MgModel,
   SUM(MgIn) summedValue
   FROM Table1
  GROUP BY MgName,MgModel
) t
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON t.MgName = Table2.McName AND t.MgModel = Table2.McModel;
```

The inner query gets the summed value for each `<MgName,MgModel>` pair. Then a `LEFT JOIN` between this result and `Table2` would get the corresponding `McOut` value for each `<MgName,MgModel>` pair (if exists in `Table2`).

Finally the difference of the `summed value` and `McOut` would make final result.

Comment: LEFT JOIN Table2 ON t.MgName = Table2.McName AND t.MgModel = Table2.MgModel;    MgModel  error if it possible McModel